# I can not get to set the color for SPAN element

Tags: css

I can not get to set the color for SPAN element. The text is an inside label for an input field.

The text is WHITE and I need to it to be BLACK.

I tried this (but not working):

```
span.main-label span{color: black!important;}
```

The html is

```
<span class="sub-label-true"><span class="main-label"><span>Name</span></span><span class="sub-label"><span>your full name</span></span></span>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you prepare a snippet? I cannot open the link you provided.

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: Check your CSS, perhaps after the line with "span.main-label span{color: black!important;}" there is another line of CSS where this property is overridden with #fff color. Can you provide a screenshot of the inspector in any browser, where it shows the CSS properties?

Answer (score -1):

It's not text color you're looking for, you need the placeholder color, which is set differently:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

**Edit:**

I added `!important` but I don't recommend you use it. I placed it here because I can't find whatever is setting white placeholder text in your code.

Comment: The question talks about a span, not the placeholder

Comment: I don't think he knows what the proper terminology is. He has placeholders within html that aren't visible. His span is only used for error messages and it's not white, it's red.

Comment: Question is not clear... He says a "white text" inside a span... but the span is red... and the placeholder is white... I don't think a downvote is fairly here...

Comment: OP has a language or understanding barrier, doesn't mean we need to downvote him.